# How do you add Meta-Description with Metatag?

Tags: nodes, meta-tags

In the Node's options for [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag), I have a token for the metatag "Description", i.e.: `[node:summary]`.

If I want to write the description, should I delete it? Or write it in where the "summary" appears?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a manual description you should delete the whole "[node:summary]" part and put your text in its place.

The square brackets are part of the token notation and aren't needed unless you are using replacement tokens.